# Usage of 'expected of' in this sentence

Tags: idioms, expressions, idiomatic-language

> Hazing is any activity *expected of someone joining or participating in a group* that humiliates, degrades, abuses, or endangers them.

I understand that 'that humiliates...' refers to the preceding 'any activity', but how am I supposed to understand 'expected of...' in between? Is there any omission between 'activity' and 'expected'?

Comment: No: there's no omission. Grammatically, the expression _(that is) expected of someone joining or participating in a group_ is a gerund-participial clause modifying "activity". You could add "that is" (as shown) to convert it into a relative clause. The expression _that humiliates, degrades, abuses, or endangers them_ refers to _activity expected of someone joining or participating in a group_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "...that is..." is omitted:

> "Hazing is any activity **that is** expected of someone joining...".

The phrase *"expected of someone joining or participating in a group"* is a relative clause with "that is" removed because it's optional.

As for the second relative clause, *"that humiliates, degrades, abuses, or endangers them"*, it can either be understood as a second relative clause modifying *"activity"*, or as a relative clause that modifies the noun phrase, "activity (that is) expected of someone joining or participating in a group".

Answer (score 0):

To more fully expand what this is saying I will re-write the sentence:

> Hazing is the actions taken by a group of people that require others that want to join the group to undertake activities that humiliate, degrade, abuse or endanger the participants.

Here the 'expected of' indicates that the current members of the group expect people who want to join the group to undertake the activities.  This has been shortened to state that the activity is expected of those who wish to join.

Comment: The sentence isn't very well expressed. It suggests that the new member is expected to do the hazing; in fact, as 'Lifelong Learner' says, it's the existing members who do it to them.

Comment: I think it means the new member is expected to submit to hazing and do what they're told to, without complaining or calling the police. Hazing often has an active component like being sent on stupid errands or being made to drink lots of alcohol (or other less enticing fluids), and a new recruit is expected to do these things if they want to fit in.

Comment: @StuartF - I know what it _means_; I was suggesting that it would be better expressed as 'which someone joining a group is expected to submit to'.

Answer (score 0):

To express that new members are expected to submit to hazing, we could say

> **Submission to** hazing, any activity that humiliates, degrades, abuses, or endangers, is expected of someone joining or participating in a group.